# android : how to stop repeat in zoom in animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Following is my zoom_in.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true" >
    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1" >
    </scale>
</set>
```

the view is zoom in three time. how I can make it to only one time

PS: `android:repeatCount="1"` is not working.

EDIT 1: my animation Util have Load animation as folowing

```
public static Animation loadAnimation(Context context, @AnimRes int id)
        throws NotFoundException {

    XmlResourceParser parser = null;
    try {
        parser = context.getResources().getAnimation(id);
        return createAnimationFromXml(context, parser);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException ex) {
        NotFoundException rnf = new NotFoundException("Can't load animation resource ID #0x" +
                Integer.toHexString(id));
        rnf.initCause(ex);
        throw rnf;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        NotFoundException rnf = new NotFoundException("Can't load animation resource ID #0x" +
                Integer.toHexString(id));
        rnf.initCause(ex);
        throw rnf;
    } finally {
        if (parser != null) parser.close();
    }
```

now I have called it as following

```
zoomIn = loadAnimation(getContext(),
            R.anim.zoom_in);
view.startAnimation(zoomIn);
```

Comment: what if you don't mention `android:repeatCount='"1"`

Comment: also try adding `AnimationListener` in code and stop animation in `onAnimationEnd ` method.

Comment: If I don't mention repeat count it is zooming in 3 times. and If I put repeat count it also repeat 3 times.

Comment: show me your java code and try second option also..

Comment: @ELITE please ckeck my code once is ther any mistake ?

Comment: try below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set repeat count to 0

```
zoomIn = loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.zoom_in);
zoomIn.setRepeatCount(0);
```

Add `AnimationListener` to `zoomIn` like below

```
zoomIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // clear animation here
        view.clearAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of using "set" try "objectAnimator" :

```
 <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="0"
    android:fromYScale="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="1"
    android:repeatCount="1" />
```